# Convert currency to float (and parentheses indicate negative amounts)

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I have a df with currency:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Currency':['$1.00','$2,000.00','(3,000.00)']})

     Currency
0       $1.00
1   $2,000.00
2  (3,000.00)
```

I want to convert the 'Currency' dtype to float but I am having trouble with the parentheses string (which indicate a negative amount). This is my current code:

```
df[['Currency']] = df[['Currency']].replace('[\$,]','',regex=True).astype(float)
```

which produces an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: (3000.00)
```

What I want as dtype float is:

```
     Currency
0       1.00
1   2000.00
2  -3000.00
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just add `)` to the existing command, and then convert `(` to `-` to make numbers in parentheses negative.  Then convert to float.

```
(df['Currency'].replace( '[\$,)]','', regex=True )
               .replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).astype(float))

   Currency
0         1
1      2000
2     -3000
```

Comment: @JohnE, if I may add to the almost perfect answer:

`df['Currency'].replace(
    '[\$,)]','', regex=True ).replace(
    '[(]','-', regex=True).replace(
    '[ ]+', 'NaN', regex=True).astype(float)`

Comment: @JohnE, sorry I should have clarified that this replaces blanks (any number of contiguous spaces) with 'NaN', as blanks will fail at `.astype(float)`

Comment: @rohit_wason  OK, gotcha, it's a good point.  Here's what you suggest with a little extra tweaking to also handle an empty string:  `(df['Currency'].replace( '[\$,) ]+','',regex=True ).replace( '[(]','-',     regex=True ).replace( '', 'NaN',     regex=True ).astype(float))`  If you want to write that up I'll be happy to upvote.  You might also want to add some additional rows with spaces to demonstrate.  If you don't want to, I can add it to mine altho mine is so old I'm a little reluctant to change it much at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This is if you want to make sure its added to the DataFrame.

`df['Currency']=(df['Currency'].replace( '[\$,)]','', regex=True ) .replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).astype(float))`