# Get a subset of a data frame into a matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

[image]

I want just the numbers under August  - September to be placed into a matrix, how can I do this?

I tried this `cf = df.iloc[:,1:12]` which gives me but it gives me the headers as well which I do not need.

I did this

```
cf = df.iloc[:,1:12]
cf = cf.values
print(cf)
```

which gives me

```
[['$0.00 ' '$771.98 ' '$0.00 ' ..., '$771.98 ' '$0.00 ' '$1,543.96 ']
 ['$1,320.83 ' '$4,782.33 ' '$1,320.83 ' ..., '$1,954.45 ' '$0.00 '
  '$1,954.45 ']
 ['$2,043.61 ' '$0.00 ' '$4,087.22 ' ..., '$4,662.30 ' '$2,907.82 '
  '$1,549.53 ']
 ..., 
 ['$427.60 ' '$0.00 ' '$427.60 ' ..., '$427.60 ' '$0.00 ' '$427.60 ']
 ['$868.58 ' '$1,737.16 ' '$0.00 ' ..., '$868.58 ' '$868.58 ' '$868.58 ']
 ['$0.00 ' '$1,590.07 ' '$0.00 ' ..., '$787.75 ' '$0.00 ' '$0.00 ']]
```

I need these to be of floating types.

Comment: Depending on your pandas version, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values or https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html should do the trick. (You'll need to subset first, of course.)

Comment: @Evan Those did not really help me but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given (stealing from an earlier problem today):

```
"""
IndexID IndexDateTime IndexAttribute ColumnA ColumnB
   1      2015-02-05        8           A       B
   1      2015-02-05        7           C       D
   1      2015-02-10        7           X       Y
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=["IndexDateTime"]).set_index(["IndexID", "IndexDateTime", "IndexAttribute"])
```

df:

```
                                     ColumnA ColumnB
IndexID IndexDateTime IndexAttribute                
1       2015-02-05    8                    A       B
                      7                    C       D
        2015-02-10    7                    X       Y
```

using

```
df.values
```

returns

```
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['C', 'D'],
       ['X', 'Y']], dtype=object)
```

To subset, you can use a couple of techniques. Here,

```
df.loc[:, "ColumnA":"ColumnB"]
```

Returns all rows and slices from `ColumnA` to `ColumnB`. Other options include syntax like `df[df["column"] == condition]` or `df.iloc[1:3, 0:5]`; which approach is best more or less depends on your data, how readable you want your code to be, and which is fastest for what you're trying to do. Using `.loc` or `.iloc` is usually a safe bet, in my experience.

In general for pandas problems, it is helpful to post some sample data rather than an image of your dataframe; otherwise, the burden is on the SO users to generate data that mimics yours.

Edit:
To convert currency to float, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464280/converting-currency-with-to-numbers-in-python-pandas):

```
df.replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

So, in a one-liner,

```
df.loc[:, "ColumnB":"ColumnC"].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).values.astype(float)
```

yields

```
array([[1.23, 1.23],
       [1.23, 1.23],
       [1.23, 1.23]])
```

Comment: Edited. Portions of your question were already answered elsewhere on SO; as such, your question isn't an exact duplicate, but I think you should spend some time googling SO to see what other people have tried to address smaller segments of the project you're working on.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(641.99)'

Comment: Ah, the `()` tripped up the replacement values. If you're dealing with accounting data, I think that might be a negative number... so you'll need to adjust accordingly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521526/convert-currency-to-float-and-parentheses-indicate-negative-amounts